# Choose file name and saving directory

Tags: javafx, directory, save

I use DirectoryChooser to choose where the file will be save

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
    Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
    File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(stage);

    File file = null;

    if(selectedDirectory!=null){
        file = new File(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+"\\"+"test"+".txt");
        try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file)){
            gson.toJson(data,fileWriter);
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO Error");
        }
    }
```

It works well, but I'd like to be able to write the file name, like this:
[image]

but instead I can only choose the path folder:
[image]

How can I change the code to get the window like in the first picture?

Comment: use a FileChooser (vs. a DirectoryChooser)

Comment: @kleopatra isn't file chooser for opening files? I'd like to save my file

Comment: api doc is your friend :)

Comment: "_isn't file chooser for opening files?_" – yes, but also for saving: [`FileChooser#showSaveDialog(Window)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showSaveDialog(javafx.stage.Window)).